# Dockerfile to copy files

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm writing a Dockerfile to create a nginx image with basic http authentication. I need to copy my local nginx.conf file and a file containing login information (htpasswd) and am writing it into my Dockerfile but it doesn't seem to be working. When I look at the nginx.conf in the container it is still the default and the authentication functionality is not present on the webpage. Help?

```
FROM nginx:latest

ADD ./gilbard /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./htpasswd /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd

# Expose port
EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct.

If the `COPY` files did not exist in the working directory, the build would generate an error.

Perhaps there's a mistake in your build|run commands, please add these to your question.

I am able to repro your question and my `nginx.conf` is copied correctly.

```sh
more ./nginx.conf
Hello Freddie

docker build --tag=58188265 --file=./Dockerfile .

docker run --interactive --tty 58188265 /bin/sh -c "more /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
Hello Freddie
```

Answer (score -1):

the nginx.conf file is locally stored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, atleast on a ubuntu machine.

It looks like you're dockerfile is copying nginx.conf using the current location of the Dockerfile.

Do you have the nginx.conf stored in the same directory as your Dockerfile?

In other words, your COPY should look like:

```
COPY /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

However there may be permissions issues with this. I'm not too sure but give that a try!

Another alternative is to do:

```
sudo docker cp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf container_id:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: Turns out I was still using a previous image to build the container from, thank you though!

Comment: This answer is misleading. The source of the `COPY` command is a relative path to the build context, not to the host filesystem.

Comment: As mentioned, "using the current location of the Dockerfile" means the build context, not the host file system. Don't think thats misleading at all

Comment: The alternative given uses a host path rather than a context relative path. The `/etc` in the source is two different things in your different examples. Particularly since this points to changing from an explicit relative path with `./` to an implicit but confusingly named relative starting with `/etc` I think it's misleading. It also doesn't answer the question since an invalid path would result in a fail to build rather than the old file.

Comment: Build context is also not the same thing as the location of the Dockerfile. While they default to the same location, they can be independently configured.